# Flutter- can't build ios via VSCode , only via Xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have some problems with Flutter:

Android gradle build is extreme slow at first run. But in the end it works, on simulator and real device.
Ios build instead won't work, after a morning of trying and a complete restart of the project the best result i have obtained is:

- I can build the project in Xcode with a manual click on "Run". (physical device)
- I can't build the project in VSCode, it returns this error :

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47633

The issue is still open, and i have tried the solutions posted on that link.

So the ones who have the same error like me can't use a real device to test Ios build? It seems to strange, maybe there is a solution not posted on the git.

There is someone that stuck in a similar situation?  Or maybe there are something else i can try?

This is my flutter doctor with an android device connected but it's all ok also with Ios:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 1.22.1 at /Users/usermac/flutter
    • Framework revision f30b7f4db9 (8 days ago), 2020-10-08 10:06:30 -0700
    • Engine revision 75bef9f6c8
    • Dart version 2.10.1

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/usermac/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.0.1, Build version 12A7300
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.15.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • A3 Pro (mobile) • A3PRO201809054022 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
```